# Wanting an opinion on whether I should run my data as a correlation, comparison, or as a chi squared?

Tags: r, correlation, chi-squared-test

## Problem:

I am trying to analyze my data being the color of my seeds (SEED COLOR) vs how the roots turned out when harvested (ROOT COLOR) and compare the two. I converted all of the colors to a number scale, being 1-6. Each number is a different color, but the color scale is the same for both of my columns.

### Possible solutions:

I have ran my data through as a correlation, and chi squared but I get strange results each time. I wanted to see if I could get the community's input on what a valid form of data analysis I could use. I want to say my answer is a correlation, but I cannot produce graphs that show one.[image: my data]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to be able to say about your data? In other words, why do anything with your data?

Comment: If there's no meaning to the numbers--if they're just arbitrary codes--then this won't help you; it will only give you deceptive results.  A good place to start would be by looking at the *contingency table:* namely, the matrix of counts of all possible combinations of root color and seed color.

Comment: If you were to make a 5×5 table for seed color and root color as categorical variables, you would have 25 cells is the table. However, I see only 15 color pairs. Thus you would have, on average, less than one count per cell, which is not enough data for a successful Chi-squared test. // Kendall's $\tau$ is a measure of categorical association.  You might look at the definition,
computation, and uses of Kendal's corr to see if
matches your objectives. // A difficulty is that each category has only one member.

Comment: @Bruce It's not that bad.  There are effectively only three root colors (removing a single yellow root), leaving 26 observations among 15 cells for a mean of 1.7 per cell.  In a table this size that's enough not only to see major patterns, but even for the chi-squared statistic to have approximately a chi-squared distribution, provided there are no extremely low-count rows or columns. But since there's no formal hypothesis, we ought to be advising about *exploratory* methods, not hypothesis testing.